# PyCharm - how do I debug (like in Jupyter Notebook) without having to re-run the full script every-time that I modify code?

Tags: python, debugging, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I'm new to coding and to PyCharm. I've learned with Jupyter and trying to get my head around PyCharm debugging (using single/multiple breakpoints).

What I liked about Jupyter is that when you put your code into different blocks, run them to output lists which you'll then be working with (the lists - as long as you haven't done anything to permanently affect them, but in that case, I would do `new_list = og_list.copy()` and play with the new list, to avoid re-running all of the code above) to create/test your next lines of codes, I can't figure out a way to proceed in the same way into PyCharm/Debugging.

In PyCharm, the way that I am using it, it seems that every time that I am changing a line of code to re-test/debug, I need to run the full code once again. I know I must be doing it wrong. I've played a few videos now and read a few posts online but I still can't seem to get it. Anyone here available to help?

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that you could write [jupyter notebooks in PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/jupyter-notebook-support.html)? - The cell functionality of jupyter notebook is only given in jupyter notebook and ipython as far as I know.

You may also open a [iPython-shell](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/ipython.html) in PyCharm.

Also, remember that you can easily convert a jupyter notebook to a .py-File, so nothings prevents you from writing code in jupyter notebook.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that! I'm gonna try it. But also, as I'm slowly progressing, I'd rather learn how to properly use PyCharm and code fast into PyCharm, the way that good (fast/efficient) coders do to eventually make it a profession.

Comment: then i would rly recommend to you learn the hotkeys for PyCharm

and also a good start to get a overview over PyCharm is  [this youtube playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPC-bGdBSM8&list=PLQ176FUIyIUZ1mwB-uImQE-gmkwzjNLjP) and this [tip video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NoDx0MEESDw) from intellij